# accessing the length of array in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have to send an array to an ejs file .Nodejs(Express) server code:

```
      response.redirect('file',{array : someArray });
```

How can I access the array length in ejs :

```
      <p><%= array.length %></p>
```

The above code in ejs file is not correct.This produces an error .How do I solve it ?

Comment: Can you provide more code of the server-side and the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```js
response.render('file', { array: someArray }); // in the server code
```

Make sure Your `ejs` file `file.ejs` is in a folder called `views`.

Then you can access the array `length`

```html
<p><%= array.length %></p>
```